# How to prevent clicking while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider made on the basis of scroll. The slider was made specifically for the adaptive. But from dekstop I had a problem. When I start to swipe scroll I have links clicked automatically. How can I prevent it?

```
$('.js_slider-item').on('dragstart', function() {
    return false;
});

// slider
$('.js_slider-viewport').each(function() {
        var slider = $(this),
            sliderClosest = $(this).closest('.js_slider'),
            sliderMouse = false,
            sliderPos,
            sliderX,
            scroll,
            movePos,
            moveX,
            moveWalk;

        // mousedown
        slider.on('mousedown', function(e) {
            sliderMouse = true;

            sliderPos = slider.offset();
            sliderX = e.pageX - sliderPos.left;
            scroll = slider.scrollLeft();
        });

        // mouseleave
        slider.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
            sliderMouse = false;
        });

        // mouseup
        slider.on('mouseup', function(e) {
            sliderMouse = false;
        });

        // mousemove
        slider.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            if (!sliderMouse) return;
            e.preventDefault();

            movePos = slider.offset(),
            moveX = e.pageX - sliderPos.left,
            moveWalk = (moveX - sliderX) * 2;

            slider.scrollLeft(scroll - moveWalk);
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xLwDgZODc/52dwu7v9/17/

Comment: I checked your code it is working fine. Both on desktop and mobile.

Comment: On jsfiddle it is not noticeable. But if you try to locally scroll then you will notice that links are clicked during scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to divert all the click event over document or window so that it will not do default behavior on click anywhere in the page (document/window)

code might look like (sample code -sudo code)

```
// override the click all over the window 
$(document).on('click' function () {
  // console.log(' click is not allowed while scrolling');
alert('clicked blocked ');
})//
```

Then once user stopped scrolling, you can remove the click listener

```
// remove event listener from document
$(document).removeEventListener("click",  function () {
  // console.log(' click is not allowed while scrolling');
alert('clicked blocked ');
});
```